# How to replace a value/string from a column in a data frame?

Tags: python, excel, string, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace some strings in a column from a data frame which is like this

```
    df["column"]
------------------
 1. Ne Road
 2. Rosemarys street se
 3. Plunkett pkwy
 4. like that so on.....
```

like these there are thousands of values
Here i want to replace Ne to NE, se to SE, pkwy to Parkway like that

So here is my code:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

my_text = df.iloc[:,2] -----### '2' is the Column number here in my Dataframe ###

reps = {
'se' : 'SE'
'Ne' : 'NE'
'pkwy' :'"Parkway'
}

df["column"] = replace_all(my_text,reps)
```

I want to know where I went wrong and please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `apply` with `lambda`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

def replaceString(val):
    reps = {
        'se' : 'SE',
        'Ne' : 'NE',
        'pkwy' :'"Parkway',
        'sw': "SW",
        'rd':"Road"
    }
    for key, v in reps.items():
        if key in val:
            val = val.replace(key, v)
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame({"column": ['Ne Road', 'Rosemarys street se', "Plunkett pkwy", "sw Trampoline rd"]})
print(df["column"].apply(replaceString))
```

**Output:**

```
0                NE Road
1    RoSEmarys street SE
2      Plunkett "Parkway
3     SW Trampoline Road
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, After applying the replaceString method,I want my data to be stored in the same column, i.e., inside df["column"], How to do that?

Comment: `df["column"] = df["column"].apply(replaceString)` ?

Comment: I am getting an error --object of type 'NoneType' has no len()--, Since There are some values which the apply method is not applicable, So i want the same data to be reflected in df["column"]

Comment: The error looks unrelated to the above snippet. Are you using `len()` in your code?

Comment: Rakesh, ignore my last question, If there is one or more change in the same line i.e., in df["column"], The change is reflecting in only one place              For eg: "sw Trampoline rd" should be changed to "SW Trampoline Road"                                                                                                     But only "sw" is changing to SW,"rd" is left out and its going to next one.Could you please help me out?  thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with argument `regex=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['Ne Road', 'Rosemarys street se',
                              'Plunkett pkwy', 'like that so on']})

reps = {'se' : 'SE', 'Ne' : 'NE', 'pkwy': 'Parkway'}

df['column'] = df['column'].replace(reps, regex=True)

print(df)

                column
0              NE Road
1  RoSEmarys street SE
2     Plunkett Parkway
3      like that so on
```